# Sql connection works with MySql.Data but not with Dapper/IDbConnection with path not found error

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, dapper, mysql.data

I am trying to change my SQL connections from using MySql.Data to using Dapper to retrieve my data from a MySQL database running on a VPS. I have no problems connecting with the following connection class with MySql.Data

```
class Connection
{
    MySqlConnection conn;
    static string host = "Fake Name";
    static string database = "Fake Database";
    static string userDB = "Fake User";
    static string password = "Fake Password";
    
    public bool Open()
    {
        try
        {
            strProvider = "Server=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";User ID=" + userDB + ";Password=" + password;
            conn = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
            conn.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Error ! " + er.Message, "Information");
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
    public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            da.Fill(ds, "result");
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public MySqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return reader;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            int affected;
            MySqlTransaction mytransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mytransaction.Commit();
            return affected;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

However I'm trying to switch to Dapper so I can securely manage queries. I'm using the code below

```
DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
bookingList = db.GetBookings(BookingCalendar.SelectionStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));



public class DataAccess
{
    public List<Booking> GetBookings(string date) 
    {           
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.connectionString("Fake Name")))
        {
            return connection.Query<Booking>($"select * from Bookings WHERE Date ='{date}'").ToList();
        }
    }
}



public static class Helper
{
    public static string connectionString(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
    }
}



<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Fake Name" connectionString="Server=Fake IP; Database=Fake Database; User Id=Fake User; Password=Fake Password providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

but on trying to open the connection I get a path not found error after 15 seconds. I'm not sure why this is happening as these two connection strings are identical. Any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: Actually I was following IAmTimCorey's (on Youtube) tutorial on c# mysql the easy way https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Et2khGnrIqc&t=602s  Edit: Maybe you were confused by the code block that looks like its one class but its actually snippets from 3 classes and an app.config?

Comment: Also missing a whole bunch of `using` and there's some scary looking SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it doesn't work. You're using `SqlClient` in the second code snippet, which is specific to SQL Server. If you want to connect to MySQL then you still need to use a MySQL provider.